# power BI (DAX) show value

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
#5PPTOKG-PZPrueba =
CALCULATE(
SUM(BD_Planeacion[PreSsupuesto KG]),
BD_Planeacion[Region] in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Region]),
BD_Planeacion[Predio]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Predio]),
BD_Planeacion[Semana]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Semana]),
BD_Planeacion[Año]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Año]),
VariedadOW[Variedades] in VALUES(VariedadesGHS[Variedades])
)
```

Show value in power bi (DAX), hide the value when the table     `VariedadOW[Variedades]`     is at 0 and     `VariedadesGHS[Variedades]<>BLANK()`

Answer (score 0):

```
#5PPTOKG-PZPrueba =
CALCULATE(
SUM(BD_Planeacion[PreSsupuesto KG]),
BD_Planeacion[Region] in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Region]),
BD_Planeacion[Predio]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Predio]),
BD_Planeacion[Semana]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Semana]),
BD_Planeacion[Año]in VALUES(SQLSeguimientoEmbarques[Año]),
VariedadOW[Variedades] in VALUES(VariedadesGHS[Variedades]),
NOT( VariedadOW[Variedades] = 0 && VariedadesGHS[Variedades] <> BLANK() )
)
```

?